# XAML Templated Control how to write somthing like SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, winrt-xaml

I am creating my first custom control by Templated Control. Now it works fine, but I don't know how to get SelectedItem in my table:

```
<Style TargetType="local:DiaryControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DiaryControl">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid Column="0" Margin="20,0,10,0">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Column="1" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid Column="2" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" FontSize="18" SelectedIndex="{Binding Reason, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
                                            <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </Grid>
                                    ...
                                    <Grid Column="5" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                                        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Comment}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For example, when I touch TextBox, TextBlock etc. in the generated table, I want something like SelectedItem in control, to do an action with selected object.

Who can help? Where I can learn about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i need to add ICommand to class Student from Students collection

```
public ICommand Process
{
    get
    { 
        return new RelayCommand<object>((arg) => 
        {
            Student button = arg as Student;
            ----do something
        }
    });
}
```

and in XAML: Command="{Binding Process}", CommandParameter="{Binding}"